# JavaScript code changes all image instead of desired image on combobox output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

My code works how i want it to as in, when a certain value from the combobox is selected the image changes to the correct image. However its not just the image i want to change that changes. its all the image i have on that html page(logo, widget images, ect). i dont want this to happen but only my desired image. Here is my code:

html:

```
<form name="animals">
<select id="imagecb">
    <option value="option1" selected>Please select... </option>
    <option value="option2">cat</option>
    <option value="option3">dog</option>
    <option value="option4">bird</option>
    <option value="option5">hamster</option>
</select><br />
</form>
<!-- This is the desired image to change via the selected option in the selectbox -->
<img src="(url)cat.png" />
```

javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery( function ($) { 
var pictureList = [
    "(url)cat.png",
    "(url)dog.png",
    "(url)bird.png",
    "(url)hampster.png" 
    ];
$('#imagecb').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find( ':selected' ).index();
    $('img').attr( "src", pictureList[index] );
});
});
</script>
```

If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: _"hampster"_?  Don't you mean _"hamster"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this
`$('img').attr( "src", pictureList[index] );`

it will change all images at your page.

Try to add a class on those image tag which you want to change.
like 
`<img class="change_image" ..... </img>`

now change at javascript
`$('.change_image').attr( "src", pictureList[index] );`

Comment: Thanks for the help and explaining what was wrong :) Worked fine after that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly identify the target image.

```
$('img').attr( "src", pictureList[index] );
```

This `img` selector targets *all* `<img>` elements on your page. Use an `id` instead:

```
<img id="targetImage" src="(url)cat.png" />
```

```
$('#targetImage').attr( "src", pictureList[index] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a way to identify the image you want to change. For example, add an id attribute:

```
<img src="(url)cat.png" id="myImage />
```

Than, use this id when changing the src tag:

```
$('img#myImage').attr( "src", pictureList[index] );
```